# C# equivalent of Java class level fields

Tags: java, c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm new(er) to C# than I am to Java and I'm attempting to convert some of my java automation tests into C#.
My question is about following code:

```
public class UnitTest1
{ 
    [Test]
    public void loginTest()
    {
        //path variable points to the chrome driver exe bin location
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        //pass the path to our new driver
        var driver = new ChromeDriver(path);
        //then pass the driver to our page object + add IWebdriver as a 
        //param to HomepageClass obj
        var homePage = new HomePage(driver);

        homePage.goTo();
    }
}
```

This code instantiates a new chrome driver and calls a simple goTo method on a homepage object. It also passes the driver to the homepage Object allowing the driver to interact with the page object in other ways.

The way that the code is currently written means that I would have to recreate the local variables for every future Test that I plan to script.
In a similar fashion to Java, I would like to use something equivalent to fields at class level in order for them to be reused across multiple tests in the class. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to go about this?

What I've tried so far:

I tried changing the variables to objects at class level, and initializing them in a setup method like so:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    object homePage;
    object path;
    object driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void startDriver()
    {
        //path variable points to the chrome driver bin location
        path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        //pass the path to our new driver
        driver = new ChromeDriver(path);
        //then pass the driver to our page object + add 
        //IWebdriver as a param to HomepageClass obj
        homePage = new HomePage(driver);
    }

    [Test]
    public void loginTest()
    {
        homePage.goTo();
    }
}
```

This generated the following errors, some of which I managed to fix as follows:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions'

State: fixed by: Changing: `object path;` to `ChromeOptions path;`

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions'

State: Not yet fixed. This was generated as a result of fixing the first error

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver'

State: fixed by : Changing `object driver;` to `IWebdriver driver;`

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'goTo' and no extension method 'goTo' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

State: not yet fixed

Any advice appreciated

Comment: Seems like `path` should be `string` and `homePage` should be `HomePage` and `driver` should be `ChromeDriver`.  I'm curious how you could do this in Java without specifying the types.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is untested, and only based on your errors:

Your [`Path.GetDirectoryName(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_GetDirectoryName_System_String_) returns a `string`, so instead of `object path;` or `ChromeOptions path;` it should be `string path;` instead.

As for your last quoted error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'goTo' and no extension method 'goTo' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This means you are currently trying to use the `.goTo` on the `object homePage`, and the `object`-class obviously doesn't has any `goTo` method.
This can be fixed by either changing `object homePage;` to `HomePage homePage`, or alternatively change `homePage.goTo();` to `((HomePage)homePage).goTo();` (I would suggest the first).

Not sure where the first quoted error is coming from, since I don't see any `ChromeOptions` in your `startDriver()` method, but I would also change `object driver;` to `ChromeDriver driver;`.

---

**TL;DR:**

Change:

```
object homePage;
object path;
object driver;
```

to:

```
HomePage homePage;
string path;
ChromeDriver driver;
```

PS: Similar errors would occur in Java when you would have `Object` variables on class-level without using casts in the code.

Answer (score 2):

The first error you received:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions'

wasn't so much telling you to change the type of your path variable to `ChromeOptions`, but was telling you that the `ChromeDriver` constructor takes a type of `ChromeOptions` rather than a generic `object`.

The documentation is decent for this and should always be the first place you look when working with unfamiliar types (https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html)

Based on the documentation for `ChromeOptions`, you can specify the path to the Chrome binary by doing the following:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.setBinary(new File(path));
```

You can always move the options variable to the class level and initialise once if that's what you want to do.

To expand on Kevin's answer - it's generally best not to simply declare something as an object unless absolutely necessary as you won't be able to call any type specific methods on the `object` without casting it first